# UIPanGestureRecognizer not moving UIImages smoothly and rendering occurs?

Tags: ios, uipangesturerecognizer

I am facing problem in my project my purpose of project is to add many `UIImages` on the starting and these images should be drag and drop able, for that I uses `UIPanGestureRecognizer` but still facing problem please help me out Thanks in advance.

this code is in my `viewdidload` method

```
 UIView *holderView = [[UIView alloc]init];

for (int i = 0; i<=4; i+=1) {

    NSMutableArray * images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"iphone-status-bar.png",@"uiswitch.png",@"NavigationBar.png",@"barbutton.png",@"ios-back-button.png", nil];


    NSString * image_name= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[images objectAtIndex:i]];

//  NSLog(@"%@",image_name);

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:image_name];

    holderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, i*30, image.size.width, image.size.height)];

    UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[holderView frame]];

    imageview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [imageview setImage:image];

    [holderView addSubview:imageview];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];

    [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];

    [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];

    [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];

     [holderView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];


     [self.view addSubview:holderView];
}
```

And the gesture handler is:

```
-(void)move:(id)sender {

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender view]];
    CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:self.view];

    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        firstX = [[sender view] center].x;
        firstY = [[sender view] center].y;
    }

    translatedPoint = CGPointMake(firstX+translatedPoint.x, firstY+translatedPoint.y);

    [[sender view] setCenter:translatedPoint];

    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        CGFloat finalX = translatedPoint.x + (.01*[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender velocityInView:self.view].x);
        CGFloat finalY = translatedPoint.y + (.01*[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender velocityInView:self.view].y);

        if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])) {

            if(finalX < 0) {

                finalX = 0;
            }

            else if(finalX > 768) {

                finalX = 768;
            }

            if(finalY < 0) {

                finalY = 0;
            }

            else if(finalY > 1024) {

                finalY = 1024;
            }
        }

        else {

            if(finalX < 0) {

                finalX = 0;
            }

            else if(finalX > 1024) {

                finalX = 768;
            }

            if(finalY < 0) {

                finalY = 0;
            }

            else if(finalY > 768) {

                finalY = 1024;
            }
        }

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:.35];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
        [[sender view] setCenter:CGPointMake(finalX, finalY)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a problem, you have to tell us what behavior you experienced and what you expected.

Comment: The goal I want to achieve is that when project starts on the left left side of the i Pad pane I added some random different uiimages and I want to enable them to drag and drop functionality on them but the first image I add behave properly but not other (mean other are showing random movement, sometime they start drag and drop and sometime remain still). please kindly help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally suspect the `holderView` logic. You're adding `holderView` to your controller's top level view using the vertical offset of `i * 30`, but when you're adding the `imageView` to the `holderView`, you're offsetting it within `holderView` by `i * 30` again (because you're using the `frame` of `holderView`, which has a `y` offset in it)! Worse, because your gesture recognizer is on the `holderView` and not the `imageView`, when you try to grab the `imageView` by tapping on the image, you're often going to not be over the `holderView` you thought you were, but rather one for one of the other images!

Assuming you like the way the images are laid out right now (really 60.0 points apart), then I'd suggest you change that `i*30` to `i*60.0` and either:

- change the setting of `frame` for the `imageView` to `[holderView bounds]`; or, even better,
- get rid of the `holderView` views altogether because (at least on the basis of what you've shared so far) it adds no value and only complicates the code.

As an aside, a few other observations:

- The `images` array doesn't need to be mutable, and you shouldn't be reinitializing it inside the `for` loop.
- You probably should reference `[images count]` rather than hard coding `4` in your `for` loop.

With these changes, the `viewDidLoad` code then looks like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSArray *images = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"iphone-status-bar.png",@"uiswitch.png",@"NavigationBar.png",@"barbutton.png",@"ios-back-button.png", nil];

    // if you're using a recent version of the compiler, you could simplify that further to just
    //
    // NSArray *images = @[@"iphone-status-bar.png",@"uiswitch.png",@"NavigationBar.png",@"barbutton.png",@"ios-back-button.png"];

    for (int i = 0; i < [images count]; i++) {

        NSString *imageName = [images objectAtIndex:i]; // or you could say `NSString *imageName = images[i];`
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(2.0, i * 60.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];

        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
        panRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
        panRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;

        [imageView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
    }
}
```

You can simplify your `move` routine a bit, too:

```
-(void)move:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

    static CGPoint originalCenter; // or make this a class ivar; but don't make this a global!

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        [gesture.view.superview bringSubviewToFront:gesture.view];
        originalCenter = gesture.view.center;
    }

    CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint translatedPoint = CGPointMake(originalCenter.x+translation.x, originalCenter.y+translation.y);

    gesture.view.center = translatedPoint;

    if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        CGPoint velocity = [gesture velocityInView:gesture.view];
        translatedPoint.x = MAX(translatedPoint.x + .01 * velocity.x, 0.0);
        translatedPoint.y = MAX(translatedPoint.y + .01 * velocity.y, 0.0);

        if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])) {

            translatedPoint.x = MIN(translatedPoint.x, 768.0);
            translatedPoint.y = MIN(translatedPoint.y, 1024.0);
        }
        else {

            translatedPoint.x = MIN(translatedPoint.x, 1024.0);
            translatedPoint.y = MIN(translatedPoint.y, 768.0);
        }

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             gesture.view.center = translatedPoint;
                         }
                         completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Personally, I hate seeing hard-coded coordinates, so I might further simplify the `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` code to something like:

```
if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    CGPoint velocity = [gesture velocityInView:gesture.view];
    translatedPoint.x = MAX(translatedPoint.x + .01 * velocity.x, 0.0);
    translatedPoint.y = MAX(translatedPoint.y + .01 * velocity.y, 0.0);
    translatedPoint.x = MIN(translatedPoint.x, gesture.view.superview.bounds.size.width);
    translatedPoint.y = MIN(translatedPoint.y, gesture.view.superview.bounds.size.height);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         gesture.view.center = translatedPoint;
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}
```